# ¿Cómo conectar mi aplicación en Android a un servidor de base de datos?

Tags: android, base-de-datos

voy a desarrollar una aplicación en android la cual se tiene que conectar a una base de datos que esta en un servidor local,pero quieren que a la aplicación se pueda acceder desde cualquier lugar, solo con que tenga conexión  a internet.

Comment: a que base de datos quieres conectar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En el caso de las aplicaciones moviles se debe utilizar un servicio web que este publicado en algun sitio web, esto para que el dispositivo no realice el procesamiento de la información y unicamente muestre los datos. El servicio web lo puedes hacer en cualquier tecnologia web (.NET, Java,PHP, etc...) ya tu eliges que tipo de servicio web quieres hacer, yo te recomiendo que realices un servicio de tipo REST ya que es muy sencillo y permite que las llamadas utilicen el menor ancho de banda del móvil al mandar los datos en formato JSON.

El esquema seria practicamente tu aplicación movil que se conecta a traves de llamadas HTTP o HTTPS por el metodo que requieras (POST, GET, PUT,etc...) a un servicio web en algun servidor web publicado en internet o montado en un hosting, en el servicio web haces toda la lógica de negocios, modificas, extraes datos de la base de datos y esta la mandas a tu aplicación donde presentas los datos en la pantalla.

Si tu servidor es de red local, puedes publicarla a traves de un DynDNS, No-Ip o contratar una IP Publica para tu servidor, de esta manera tu servidor local estará en acceso desde internet, el servicio web puede estar publicado en el mismo servidor o en uno aparte que acceda al servidor local unicamente, asi el dispositivo movil se conecta a un dominio en internet y el servicio hace la conexion a la base de datos de la red local y asi el dispositivo no conoce tu servidor local.

En cuanto a terminos a investigar, si es que no los conoces ya, te sugiero: Servicios web, Tipos de servicios Web, HTTP Request en Android (Existen muchas librerias que te pueden ayudar a facilitar este procesos como Volley o Retrofit) y JSON

Comment: Osea, que si se utilizan objetos JSON y conexión a través de un fichero php ¿Tan sólo tendría que dar la dirección ip del servidor al que quiera conectarme?

Comment: puedes generar apis, en cualquier tecnologia como lo dice hasta arriba .NET, Java, Ruby, una muy fácil es NODE.js con expres, ahora si no tienes base de datos creada, lo mas facil es el firebase y hay otros laboratorios que igual se van creando las tablas al vuelo, conforme haces las peticiones

Comment: tienes que generar todos tus metodos en el api, para que te regrese una lista por cada servicio y consumir tu servicio para llenar tus objetos.

Answer (score -2):

@AngelRuizC tiene razón en lo que te indico, yo le agregaría que hay otro opción y es un servicio llamado Firebase, el cual puedes utilizar de base datos y backend, así evitas crear un servicio en el servidor tu mismo.

Ambas opciones son válidas y tienen su ventajas y desventajas, una de las grandes ventajas de Firebase es qué es más fácil y rápido.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [answer] pues esto es más un comentario que una respuesta el cual no debería ir aquí