# Conectar aplicación en Android Studio a un servidor externo de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, json

Tengo una aplicación funcional en Android Studio que se basa en la conexión hacia una base de datos local. En la siguiente pregunta [¿Cómo conectar mi aplicación en Android a un servidor de base de datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11606/c%C3%B3mo-conectar-mi-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android-a-un-servidor-de-base-de-datos) Dan una respuesta general bastante buena, pero mi duda es un poco más específica.

Mi conexión yo la realizo a través del panel de control XAMPP, para la conexión a través de mysql. Siguiendo estos tutoriales de youtube: [Conectar a base de datos en Android desde 0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRD-tsACiVs&t=99s), se explica cómo realizar la conexión de forma local, introduciendo los archivos dentro de la carpeta htdocs en el directorio de instalación del XAMPP. En los tutoriales luego se explica cómo hacer una clase en Android studio que conecte a mi servidor local dando una dirección ip.

Mi carpeta htdocs, donde tengo los archivos php que necesito para mi conexión. Estos archivos me devuelven objetos JSON.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Ahora que quiero conectar ya no con un servidor local, si no con un servidor externo, ¿Hay alguna forma de conseguirlo manteniendo el sistema de archivos php que tengo ahora?

La clase que utilizo para, por ejemplo, conectar con el archivo Login que me permite hacer la primera conexión es el siguiente:

```
package com.tigestion.guillermo.agendagui;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Guillermo on 04/10/2017.
 */

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest{
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = 
         "http://192.168.1.159/Login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;
    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, 
Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("us_usuario", username);
        params.put("us_clave", password);
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){
    return params;
}
}
```

¿Habría alguna forma de cambiarlo para que en lugar de conectar a mi servidor local conecte con el servidor externo?

(Editado)

En mi archivo Gradle tengo la siguiente línea:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Y mi archivo manifest contiene lo siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

¿Es necesario algún permiso más aparte de esos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la siguiente linea de código apuntas a tu servidor:

```
 private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://192.168.1.159/Login.php";
```

En tu caso usas la IP de tu maquina, pero ahora debes apuntar a tu servidor web por ejemplo:

```
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = 
         "http://www.servidor.com/Login.php";
```

Ahora tus archivos `PHP` donde tienes tus `CRUD` debes almacenarlos en tu WebService, así como también tu base de datos. Cabe destacar que algunos atributos tal vez deban modificarse, tales como el nombre de la BD, la clave de la BD, algunos WS exigen sentencias preparadas para las conexiones, etc. Dependerá de la configuración de tu WS.

***Como ahora el uso de Internet sera fundamental en tu app, te sugiero que añadas validaciones para estos casos.***

---

- *Agregado después de los comentarios*

En términos de permiso, debes revisar que tu "servidor físico", acepte conexiones remotas,que tus `PHP` estén bien hechos con sentencias preparadas([revisar documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php))  para mayor seguridad, etc.

y por parte de Android Studio, debes dar los de Internet como mínimo.

Si tienes dudas, con gusto te ayudare en lo posible...

Comment: La respuesta es buena, pero el problema es que al parecer tengo que utilizar un servidor físico, no un servidor web. ¿Con ese sistema se podría conectar a un servidor físico? Quiero decir, ¿Son los mismos pasos?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *servidor físico* @G.Corporales? ¿Lo que intentas es conectarte a tu propia web:  `http://www.tu-web.com`?

Comment: Si por favor acláranos el termino de servidor físico ...

Comment: En la empresa en la que estoy me dicen que el servidor que tengo no es una web propiamente dicha, es una dirección IP desde la que se conectan los usuarios. La aplicación que estoy haciendo es una adaptación de una aplicación de escritorio, por lo que me han dicho que no tienen una web a la que conectarse. No se si lo he explicado bien

Comment: Entendido. Da igual que sea una IP local, una IP remota de tu empresa, etc. Se trataría de cambiar el punto de entrada (la URL de la conexión).  Ahora bien, eso tiene sus implicaciones: esa IP debe aceptar conexiones remotas, esas conexiones remotas deben ser validadas de alguna manera, la consultas a bases de datos deben ser **muy, muy seguras** ¡cuidado con la Inyección de código! Si se usará internet tendrás que otorgar permisos de conexión e implementar una verificación de la conexión antes de lanzar las peticiones al servidor. Para las peticiones yo recomendaría el uso de `Volley`.

Comment: Cuando hablamos de un ServidorWeb, no hablamos de una pagina web como tal.. En términos muy básicos es el intercambio entre aplicaciones mediante protocolos. independiente de lenguaje de programación. si tienen un servidor en tu empresa, y deseas conectarte lo puedes como te he dicho, mediante la IP,

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo entendido que la liberia de Volley se recomienda para el un trafico bajo de datos, tienes la misma información ? Creo que para tareas mas complejas se puede usar un Asynctask por ejemplo

Comment: Editada la respuesta para saber si necesito algún permiso extra aparte de los que ya tiene mi aplicación.

Comment: Hay algo de confusión con respecto a eso: 1º porque hubo un antecesor de Volley que funcionaba muy mal y mucha gente cree que el Volley actual es el mismo; 2º porque se afirma esto en la página oficial sobre la librería: ***Volley is not suitable for large download or streaming operations**, since Volley holds all responses in memory during parsing. For large download operations, consider using an alternative like **DownloadManager**.* Se refiere a no usarlo para bajar vídeos pesados a para transmitir en vivo por internet, pero para servicios REST normales es la mejor opción.

Comment: @A.Cedano si creo que muchos nos quedamos con aquella mala impresion ...

Comment: ¡Funciona perfecto! Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: @G.Corporales me alegro, no olvides la seguridad, es muy importante. Por que tendrás una gran responsabilidad si se maneja información sensible. slaudos